# Python 3.4.2 List Addition

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, addition

I'm really new at Python and programming in general. 
I'm supposed to add the first 7 numbers in the list

```
grades = [ '9', '7', '7', '10', '3', '9', '6', '6', '2' ]
```

so I wrote this code:

```
print("1.", grades[0] + grades [1] + grades [2] + grades [3] + grades [4] + grades[5] + grades[6] )
```

but it only prints out "97710396"
which is the numbers just printed out as it was an index without spaces. How do I add them so I can get 51 to print out?

Comment: The number `9` is not the same thing as the _string_ `'9'` (note the quotes). That's the crux of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without giving too much away... the "numbers" in your list are actually `string`s, and python allows you to add strings... by concatenating them together. So `'a' + 'b' + '9'` gives you `'ab9'`. You need to convert these `string`s into `int`s as `int('19')`, so `int('9') + int('7')` gives `16`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert everything to an integer, sum what you need, print it:

```
print("1.",sum(map(int, grades[:7])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert strings to `int`s to do numeric operations (instead of string concatenations):

```
grades = ['9', '7', '7', '10', '3', '9', '6', '6', '2']
grades = [int(x) for x in grades]
print("1.", grades[0] + grades[1] + grades[2] + grades[3] +
            grades[4] + grades[5] + grades[6])
```

Or, using `sum` with list slice (useful if the items to add are continuous items)

```
grades = ['9', '7', '7', '10', '3', '9', '6', '6', '2']
grades = [int(x) for x in grades]
print("1.", sum(grades[:7]))
```

Answer (score 0):

These are individual strings. You cannot do math on strings.

What happens when you do `+` on strings is called string concatenation.

ie. `'1'+'2'` will produce `'12'` and not `'3'`

You need to convert these to integers using `int()` in order to perform arithmetic.

```
var result = int('1') + int('2')
>> 3
```

So either

```
print("1.", int(grades[0]) + int(grades [1]) + int(grades [2]) + int(grades [3]) + int(grades [4]) + int(grades[5]) + int(grades[6]) )
```

or a snazzy list comprehension with [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) and [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

```
grades = [int(x) for x in grades]
print("1.", sum(grades[:7]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
for i in range(0,7):
    sum += int(grades[i])
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

The list `grades[]` contains string variables. Integers are whole numbers. You need to change the values in the `grades[]` list to integers. To do that, you need to remove the quotes around the values in `grades[]`. Then it will output the sum of all the numbers in that list. ***Hope this helps.***

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reduce` with `lambda` for this ,

```
>>> print( "1.",reduce(lambda x,y:int(x)+int(y),grades[:7]))
```

As you tagged this question with python 3.x the `reduce` is now part of `functools` module.

```
import functools
print( "1.",functools.reduce(lambda x,y:int(x)+int(y),grades[:7]))
```